# Selecting components (only in editor) created in construction script

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, editors

Question is about **Unreal Engine 4**

Is it possible to catch click (or other mouse) event on dynamically added component in editor?

For example:
I create 5 instances of StaticMeshComponent on OnConstruction function (5 would be BlueprintEditable property).
Then I would like to be able to click on one (or multiple) of them and change some values (same as if they were added using Components section).

Sample code of what I tried:

```
// ALayoutBaseActor inherits from AActor
void ALayoutBaseActor::OnConstruction(const FTransform & Transform)
{
    Super::OnConstruction(Transform);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        auto name = this->GetName();
        name += FString("-staticMesh_mesh_" + i);

        auto staticMesh = NewObject<UStaticMeshComponent>(this, *name);
        staticMesh->SetStaticMesh(staticMeshSegmentMesh);
        staticMesh->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);
        staticMesh->RegisterComponent();
        staticMesh->SetRelativeTransform(FTransform(FVector(i * 250.f, 0, 0)));

        // this works, but function is called for each component, also it does not highlight selected mesh
        staticMesh->SelectionOverrideDelegate.BindLambda([](auto &&x) { 
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("ALayoutBaseActor (%s) click"), *x->GetName());
            return false;
        });

    }
}
```

I think similar functionality works for Spline and InstancedMeshComponent, but I cannot find list of functions that needs to be overriden.

Thanks

**To clarfiy**: I need this functionality **only in editor**, not during gameplay.

Comment: Have you Enabled Click Events in the player controller?

Comment: Are they needed if I want to catch click only in editor and not during gameplay? I would like to have same selecting functionality for meshes added 'manually" using components widget and "dynamically" using construction script.